# CakePHP: What's the difference between Auth->allowedActions() and Auth->allow();

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

What's the difference between Auth->allowedActions() and Auth->allow(); ?

```
$this->Auth->allowedActions = array('index','view','archive','listarchive','viewfromcategory','tags','aboutme','contact','polls');
```

Or

```
$this->Auth->allow(array('index','view','archive','listarchive','viewfromcategory','tags','aboutme','contact','polls'));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use allow() to add more actions to the allowedActions (in addition to those already in there). And the syntax for allow() is `$this->Auth->allow('index','view');`

Comment: and to follow up no what you are implying/saying.. you would use allowedActions in the app controller ( beforeFilter ) whereas allow() would primarily be used in an individual controllers beforeFilter